# chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo not the proper function for me?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get the email address of the logged in user, not the email address of the profile. I am using chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo in my extension popup. It works fine when I a user is logged in, I get the email address. But it also gives me the email address when i am not logged in. I guess the profile is not dependent on the login status?

I am concerned with getting the wrong email address on a shared machine. How can I be sure that I am only getting the email address of the person sitting at the keyboard?

Comment: You can force the user to type in his mail. Otherwise I don't think it could be done.

Comment: Well, in that case, could I allow a user to login in with their Google email by using chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token)